# Do I need MAMP or can do it manually?

Tags: macos, web, command-line-interface, mamp

do I need to install MAMP on the MAC to run a local web server / be able to develop sites locally?
Or can I install everything manually? I went through Homebrew and it has MySQL, Apache and PHP. So the question is, can I install and run it manually without installing the mamp? Even if it were 'more complicated'?My primary goal is to learn, so I don't like installing a package (mamp) that seems to solve everything for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need mamp. All those packages are independent programs that can be installed and configured separately and on their own as you wish.

I ran all those on FreeBSD in the same way you are wanting